# Installing PyGame on Mac High Sierra with Python 3.6

Tags: python, pygame, installation, homebrew

I installed Homebrew on my terminal, but I am stuck here. It does not reconigse Homebrew. Could someone help me in order to install Pygame for Mac High Sierra with Python 3.6.

```
Last login: Wed May  9 17:03:33 on console
macs-MacBook-Pro:~ Kyle$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> The following existing directories will be made group writable:
/usr/local/bin
==> The following existing directories will have their owner set to Kyle:
/usr/local/bin
==> The following existing directories will have their group set to admin:
/usr/local/bin
==> The following new directories will be created:
/usr/local/Cellar
/usr/local/Homebrew
/usr/local/Frameworks
/usr/local/etc
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/opt
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/share
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/var
==> The Xcode Command Line Tools will be installed.

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
macs-MacBook-Pro:~ Kyle$ brew install python3

-bash: brew: command not found
```

Comment: Did the Homebrew installation complete? Did you hit "RETURN" to install the "Xcode Command Line Tools"?

Comment: You could try using the python installer and then just use pip to get pygame?

Comment: @Pierre Oops, yeah I hit enter now, it now asks for a password. /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod u+rwx /usr/local/bin
Password:

Comment: @K-Log Do I have to reinstall python or where would I go for this? I'm new to python directories.

Comment: Go to python.org and download the and download the Mac installer and follow the directions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output of your terminal, it seems the installation of Homebrew did not complete properly.

Indeed, as part of the installation, the Homebrew installer attempts to install the "Xcode Command Line Tools". For that, it asks you to press "RETURN" to confirm that you agree to install those, and then asks you for your password to obtain the permission to do it. That is, if you press RETURN and enter your password, the Homebrew installer should then be able to complete.

Once Homebrew is installed, you can use the `brew` command to install Python, similarly to your first attempt:

```
brew install python
```

Please note that `brew install python` installs Python 3. If at some point you want to install Python 2, use `brew install python@2`.